# Recursive sequence of prime

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let us construct the sequence of primes $\left \{ p_n \right \}_{n=0,1,2,\ldots}$  with the recursive rule:  
 $p_{n+1}=\min_k(p_n+k\cdot 10^{^{\left [ p_n \right ]}})$ where $[p_n]$ is number of digits of $p_{n}$ in decimal representation  ($p_{n+1}$ is the smallest prime number which in decimal representation ends with $p_n$ ). 
 For instance if $p_0=3$,and $p_0=7$  the sequence is:
 3, 1**3**, 1**13**, 2**113**,  1**2113**,  6**12113**,  11**612113**,  16**11612113**,.......
7,  1**7**,  3**17**,  6**317**,  2**6317**,  1**26317**,
2**126317**,  7**2126317**,14**72126317**,( in Bold is a previous prime in decimal representation).
 By Dirichlet theorem, for  $p_0$ prime to $2$ and $5$ the sequence does not terminate (have infinite members). Question: How big (estimate) is $p_n$? Can we in this case aply Linik`s theorem? 
Notice: the problem can be generalized to representation of primes in any base.

Comment: The $p_0=3$ sequence is tabulated at https://oeis.org/A053583 and the $p_0=7$ sequence is https://oeis.org/A053584 but it differs in its ninth term which is $372126317$ not $1472126317$. OEIS also has the sequences ending in $1$ and in $9$.